# How to get TestNG Suite name for onExecustionStart Listener method?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, listener

I am trying to send email to specific recipients when the Test Execution starts, I am using **IExecutionListener** to send email before the test starts and the email has information such as Test suite name, username and Environment being used. I was able to implement the feature but couldn't find a way to get Test suite name at ***onExecutionStart()*** method. Is there way we could access TestNG suite name within ***onExecutionStart()*** ?

Answer (score 1):

`IExecutionListener` is used to monitor when a TestNG run starts and ends. But you need `ISuiteListener` as TestNG can execute multiple suites. Implement `ISuiteListener` and you'll get access to `ISuite` which provides suite name.